# SharePoint On-premise to SharePoint online Migration

Tags: sharepoint, migration, office365, sharepoint-online

I need to migrate my SharePoint On-premise to SharePoint Online (Office 365).

I have found SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT). Below is the link for the same,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

Is it reliable or do I need to use Sharegate or Matalogix or AvePoint?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, SPMT is a reliable, free and easy to use migration solution to help you migrate content from on-premises SharePoint sites to Microsoft 365. If [SPMT-supported features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/what-is-supported-spmt) meet your requirement, you can use it.